# Unable to find ssh key using phusion/base-image

Tags: ssh, docker, dockerfile

I m actually using Docker with phusion/baseimage and I need to connect through ssh.

In the github repository (https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker), at the bottom it's written that, to use our custom public key, we had to do the following :

```
## Install an SSH of your choice.
ADD your_key.pub /tmp/your_key.pub
RUN cat /tmp/your_key.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys && rm -f /tmp/your_key.pub
```

The fact is that, when I need to ADD my public key like following :

```
ADD /home/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /tmp/id_rsa.pub
RUN cat /home/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys && rm -f /home/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I get this error in my docker build . stack in my shell command :

```
sudo docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 12.29 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.16
 ---> 5a14c1498ff4
Step 1 : MAINTAINER Thomas DUPOND <tdupond@gmail.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 96e99cf37971
Step 2 : CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4e3c1c0697ac
Step 3 : RUN rm -f /etc/service/sshd/down
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4d856cc02b9d
Step 4 : RUN /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eab6eb3a6630
Step 5 : ADD /home/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /tmp/id_rsa.pub
2015/06/29 16:11:13 /home/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: no such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong ?

*NB : My key is well generated from 4096 using rsa. It's in the /home/thomas/.ssh directory, named id_rsa.pub*

Answer (score 0):

Docker ADD looks in the Dockerfile dir. 
Run this before the docker build command:

```
cp /home/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa.pub .
```

The command in the container has access to the file /tmp/id_rsa.pub. It has no access to /home/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
It should look like this:

```
ADD id_rsa.pub /tmp/id_rsa.pub
RUN cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys && rm -f /tmp/id_rsa.pub
```